# Computer Shuts Down, BSOD, Aggravation

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, bsod

---BOUNTY & EDIT---

Ok, here is the latest update, and attached a bounty!  So I ran all of my ram sticks 1 at a time for around 24 hours each.  None of them caused a BSOD.  I ran test on all of the ram while I was running each.  So I went to put '2' in at a time (dimm 1/2). I tried to put them both in the same dual-channel.  The computer would not boot up.  I moved them to the other dual-channel (dimm 3/4) and they would not boot up.  I put one in Dimm 4 and Dimm 2.  The computer booted up.  So I played around for a little bit, shut the PC down and tried dimm 3/4 again.  The Computer would not boot up.  I tried Dimm 4/1 and the computer would not boot up.  The only way it seems to let me boot up with more than one ram stick is to use DIMM 2/4.  Is this odd?  When I opened the case the first time, they were using 2/3/4 and not dimm 1.  Is this normal of HP?  I'm not sure that I have a problem trying to boot up with dimm 1 and 1 ram stick, I will try that later.  During the single ram stick test(s), I was using DIMM 2.

---

I made a post on here a week or so ago, but my pc's condition is getting far worse.  I've done a  lot more research and have more to offer.  I upgraded to windows 8, but I had the same problem on Windows 7.

Here's my system specs: [My HP PC](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02524612&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4344130)

I want to mainly point out that it is a 250w power supply.  I got it from my brother who said that it had been crashing randomly.  It's a year or two old.

Ok, so the crashes are random, and can be while I'm doing hefty stuff, or basically sitting idle.  When it crashes, sometimes I get to see a BSOD (which saves and sometimes doesn't get to) and my screen tends to have colored lines on it.  Sometimes the PC will restart fine, and sometimes I have to wait for 10 minutes unplugged before I can start it back up.

Now when I say it wont' turn back on.. I mean: Power button shows on, fans spin, green light on back and on motherboard are on, but screen says 'no signal'

I have done every test known to man on the HDD, and everything checks out. It has 6 gigs of ram (3x2) and I am all individually, trying to get the crashes.  My CPU doesn't rut hot at any point, and theres times where the PC will set for a day, I boot up and it crashes in 10 minutes.  The PSU does get warm, and blows out warm air.  My case is cool and side is open.

Everything is integrated, there are no add-on cards, add-on GPU's,.  The only thing I would consider to be an addon is the front Media Card slots, which I rarely use.

The only thing plugged in - HDD, CPU Fan, Back Fan, Keyboard/Mouse, Ethernet Cable, and speaker input.

95% of my bsod errors are due to ntoskrnl.exe , and I did get one classpnp.sys error.

The bsods are displayed as "irql_not_less_or_equal" "internal_power_error" I've seen others, but can't remember them off the top of my head.  But they were still caused by ntoskrnl.exe.

A lot of things point to driver(s), but how can my drivers effect my PC from not turning back on for 10 minutes (sometimes more)?

Last note: The only time I've ever heard my PC beep is when I took ALL of the ram out.  Other than that, I've never heard a beep code.

--Edit--

I am down to running 1 ram stick again, which it hasn't crashed in over 12 hours. Even if the ram was good, I usually run it at 6, and at 4.. it has been crashing more so when running higher amounts of ram.  It has crashed with 1 stick in there, but not as often.

--Edit--

Ran the 1 ram stick for 24 hours without a single glitch.  So I'm switching to another ram, and putting a dot on the tag of the 1st ram stick.  I'm really trying to narrow down the problem.

Comment: zip and upload the folder C:\Windows\Minidump (SkyDrive, Dropbox) and post a link here.

Comment: I recently deleted them due to not getting any more new ones, I didn't know if this was the problem.  I think the problem is that it goes to the bsod screen, but the PC 'locks' up before it can save anything.  If I get any more today I will post some.

Answer (score 4):

See this link on a quick tutorial on how to debug BSOD.  Check your C:\windows\minidump folder for .dmp files and load them into the debugger (once installed).

This will save you TONS of time and headache trying to guess at what is causing the BSOD.  Often, it's a display driver that's doing it.

http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?docid=543301

Let me know if you have any issues.

Ensure you motherboard has the latest BIOS installed as well.

Comment: Yeah I've been reading BSODs... that's how I know it's been the ntoskrnl.exe that's been taking it down.  But how can a video driver be responsible for me not being able to turn the computer on for 10 minutes or so?

Comment: Sorry I missed the unable to turn on the PC for 10 minutes.  Does your board allow you to monitor CPU temp?

Comment: I do use SIW montior.. which CPU temp checks out good.

Answer (score 4):

As you [calculated](http://www.thermaltake.outervision.com/Power) your power needs at 239 watts, your Power Supply Unit of 250 watts may not be enough.

Power problems can explain why each component passes testing but the whole computer doesn't.
This would also explain why running on fewer memory sticks avoids crashes,
if the PSU is just on the edge of insufficient.

The free [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) utility helps in analyzing the dump,
showing in pink highlight the drivers potentially responsible for the crash.
This can point to one hardware item as misbehaving, but it won't help if the problem is with the PSU.

I suggest trying another PSU if you can exchange with another computer.

Comment: I do not have another desktop, just a laptop :(.  I do have BlueScreenView and was using that to diagnose original problems, that's how I came acrossed the ntoskrnl.exe.  That file was the main problem.  I have read a lot on google about dual-channel, and modifications can be done in BIOS.  But my bios are locked by HP.  It originally came with the 3 sticks in 2/3/4.. and would BSOD on me, and not let me start back up for awhile.  So I imagine I can eventually start it backup that way, and it will BSOD out on me again. Should I do that?

Comment: and are you sure about that calculator, mine came up to 239w.. maybe I put something on I shouldn't have? I did put '2' on the physical sockets, I didn't know if I had a single or 2.. mine is a dual core.  It does add 50w to final result.

Comment: You know best what is inside that box - I was working from specs I found on the Internet. In that case, the PSU is a real possibility.

Comment: Well money is limited.. buying a new PSU is possible.. but once I do that, my budget is gone for a minute on this PC.  :)  So if that wasn't the problem, I'd be sol for a minute.

Comment: Try a repairman with the understanding that if it's not the PSU you pay nothing. He should have one lying around. A reconditioned one for 300 watts should do.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about getting one from a friend, I don't know many repairmen lol :)  Thank you for your help and insight.

Comment: I awarded you the 100 bounty, though I never found a correct answer as I could not get a hold of a PSU. I'm going to wait until my budget opens up a little bit, 4 gigs is holding me just fine right now.  If I eventually find this to solve it, I will select your answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. Question: Did the computer come originally with 6 GB? Just to know (if my answer is correct) whether it's HP that sold you a too-cheap PSU.

Comment: The PC (HP) came originally with the 250w PSU, and 6 gigs of DDR3 memory in DIMM slots (2,3,4).  I'm currently running 4 gigs (2x2) in dimm slots 2,4.  All original parts, nothing has been 'added'.  I do believe I have the dvd drive unplugged as well.  I can throw the dvd drive in there tomorrow and see if I get any bsods.  If I do, it could be a power supply issue. -- Edit, I have not had a single BSOD since I've been running 1 ram stick, or 2 in slots 2,4.  Only had the problem booting with dual-channel ram.